# Работа с REST API через JSON ? (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

Я начинающий программист)
На сайте работодателя увидел такую формулировку.

- Навыки работы с API, в частности работы с REST API, через JSON.

Что это? Как это понять? У меня уже каша в голове. Это работа с сервером используя Get, post, delete, put или это обработка этих запросов переводя их в JSON типа - fromJson(...);

Comment: Да, с REST API обычно работают при помощи HTTP методов GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. А работать с API через JSON - обычная практика. Допустим, Вы делаете GET запрос на API. В ответ Вам пришли данные в виде JSON. Соответственно, чтобы их использовать, их нужно распарсить. К счастью, Dart, как и многие другие ЯП уже умеют парсить JSON. Конечно, есть API, которые работают через XML, но это редкость в наше время

Comment: Спасибо! Вы помогли мне убрать мой сумбур в моей голове! )